# Code only fires if I alert first

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which checks if it's the first visit of a user, and if so, should fire and launch intro.js (but that's irrelevant, it could be any code)

The problem is, the code only fires if I include an alert() before it.

Why is that? Here's the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        var areYouNew = '<?=$row77[how_many]?>';

        if(areYouNew<1){

            // ****************
            // alert('hey'); <<<--- if I uncomment this it works ok
            // ****************

            $( "#tiles li" ).first().children('.likeBtns').show().css('z-index','999999999');
            $( ".likeBtns" ).first().children('.wishIt').show().css('z-index','999999999').attr('onClick','introJs().exit()');
            function startIntroNL(){
                var intro2 = introJs();
                intro2.setOptions({
                    steps: [
                        {
                            element: '.wish_holder_indiv',
                            intro: "Your first time?",
                            position: 'right'
                        }
                    ]
                });
                intro2.onchange(function(targetElement) {  
                    $( "#tiles li" ).first().children('.likeBtns').show();
                });
                intro2.onexit(function() {
                    $( "#tiles li" ).first().children('.likeBtns').css('z-index','2');
                    $( ".likeBtns" ).first().children('.wishIt').css('z-index','2').attr('onClick','');
                });
                intro2.start();
            };
            startIntroNL();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I really don´t know the reason but try to put the startIntroNL() function outside of the $(document).ready().

Comment: @isherwood They are intro.js methods

Comment: @adearriba It's inside an if loop, therefore can't be taken out of it, that's the whole point of the loop

Comment: Does any error pop ups in the console. F12 will open the development tools. Try to check that out.

Comment: thats not a loop. A loop is a while or for. The function definition can be outside and be called from inside the if.

Comment: @adearriba Ok, it's an if statement, tried that thanks but no different.

Comment: Is it possible to show this in a jsFiddle? If `alert` makes a difference, then it's going to be a timing thing ... the alert creates a delay which allows time for the `intro.js` to download (does it download?)

Comment: It has document.ready, it should execute after everything is loaded. Maybe the order of scripts is wrong.